# How to Update drupal 7.17 from drupal 7.17 into 7.18

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How it will upgrade to lower version into 7.18 version.
  I have got 'A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding.
  You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.
  Script: modules/contrib/jquery_update/replace/jquery
  /1.5/jquery.min.js?v=1.5.2:16'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should deactivate jquery update module while updating drupal?

Here is my standard way to do minor upgrade(7.17 -> 7.18).

- Put site in maintenance mode.
- Backup all files with ftp.
- Backup database.
- Download new drupal version and uncompress.
- Check the current drupal installation for stuff that i dont wanna replace(sites and profiles).
- Delete old core files/dirs and upload new core files with ftp without replacing sites and double check so i wont delete profile in profiles dir.
- Run update.php
- Update contrib modules(one by one) and run update.php, if something break i have a chance to find the problem.